# Reaction of 2-ethyl-5-methyl-3-phenylfuran under acidic conditions

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, heterocyclic-compounds

[image: Reaction of title compound with acid and heat]

I was asked:

> 1. Does protonation occur to the electronegative oxygen?
> 2. What is the function of the heat?

I think that there will be protonation at C-3 which will break the aromaticity and the ring will open to form a diketone product.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer looks perfectly reasonable. Acid hydrolysis of furans is a well established route to 1,4 diketones. The heat is required to overcome the resonance stabilisation of the furan ring.